# Detect whether the connection exists between fields in Dynamics-AX-2012

Tags: sql, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, morph-x

I have two tables, table1(fields: playerId, insuranceId) and table2.

How to determine from table2 if the playerId and insuranceId have a connection to each other?

I mean which player have agreement with which insurance company...

I know that I should override method(which one?) in table to and use table1 exist method to make it work, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you provide fiels of table2 ?

Comment: playerId, insuranceId and scoutId

Comment: it's just a sample project to understand basics :))))

Comment: If the tables are related, and the table design follows the Best Practices, there should be some relations or/and delete actions. You can check this quickly in the AOT.

Comment: @TBM - I hope you're not just coming here to get your homework done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't sure I understand you correctly, but you create next method on table2

```
public boolean existInTable1()
{
    table1 t;
    ;
    select recid from t where t.playerid == this.playerid && t.insuranceid == this.insuranceid;

    return (t.recid !== 0);
}
```

And somewhere in code:

```
table2 t2;
;
select t2;
if(t2.existInTable1()) ...
```

**Updated**

Of course, if you have exist-method on table1 you can rewrite existInTable1() like this:

```
public boolean existInTable1()
{
    ;
    return table1::exist(this.playerid, this.insuranceid);
}
```